# How to create 100% stacked chart using vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created a 100% stacked chart using amCharts library but because the rendering takes long I rather to create a simple one myself but I have no idea how to  do it:

Here is what I want :

[image]

I give the data to a function and it renders the chart with different color and shows the viewer how many percent each color takes.

the above image is showing this object:

```
{
   white: 10,
   red: 5,
   orange: 3,
   green: 5,
   blue: 2,
},
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Rojo the OP has plenty of rep and should know better than to ask such a broad question.

Comment: It's interesting for me how you are bound to rules even in internet... :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you haven't thought of the simplest solution (at least, I think this is the simplest :) ):

```js
const stacked = {
  white: 10,
  red: 5,
  orange: 3,
  green: 5,
  blue: 2,
};

const container = document.getElementById("container");

const addElement = (color) => {
  return `<div class="chart-element" style="background-color: ${color}"></div>`
}

(function(data, container) {
  html = ''
  for (let key in data) {
    html += addElement(key)
  }
  // using fr units ensures that they are stacked to 100%
  container.style.gridTemplateColumns = Object.values(data).map(val => `${val}fr`).join(" ")
  container.innerHTML = html
})(stacked, container);
```

```css
.chart-element {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  height: 20px;
}

#container {
  display: grid;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

I used simple `div`s & CSS grid with a dynamic number of columns and `fr` units.

Answer (score 4):

I'd like to present an alternative approach. If you're dynamically creating an image, **I would reach for [SVG](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/svg)**. `div` and `span` (+ CSS) can visually work in many cases, but those elements aren't really intended for this particular purpose, imho.

In addition, your example data object is passing presentation details (colors) inward, which are things I would try to better [encapsulate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Encapsulation), if you can. I don't know your exact use case, but it seems ideal to **define the colors *inside* with your chart logic, rather than *outside* with your data**.

Finally - and this goes along with the last point - I would recommend that you **pass semantic information inward (probably instead of the color names)**. What does your data actually represent? This is important for a11y (accessibility) purposes. Note that I'm not an expert in a11y, but here's my best shot at it along with examples of my other points (notice how you can hover over sections of the chart to see a tooltip and the data [appears](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/accessibility/reference/#pane) in the [accessibility tree](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Accessibility_tree)):

```js
const generateChart = (() => {
  const CHART_COLORS = ['white', 'red', 'orange', 'green', 'blue'];
  
  return (svgEl, obj) => {
    const nameSpace = svgEl.getAttribute('xmlns') ?? 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';
    const entries = Object.entries(obj);

    // Clear svg.js-chart's child elements
    while (svgEl.firstChild) svgEl.lastChild.remove();

    // Set virtual width/height of SVG canvas
    const width = entries.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr[1], 0);
    const height = width / 10;
    svgEl.setAttribute('viewBox', `0 0 ${width} ${height}`)

    // Add a rect.chart__bar to svg element for each entry (in a <g> tag)
    let lastX = 0;
    let colorIdx = 0;
    for (const [itemText, itemCount] of entries) {
      const displayText = `${itemText} (${itemCount})`;
      const groupEl = document.createElementNS(nameSpace, 'g');
      groupEl.setAttribute('aria-label', displayText);

      const titleEl = document.createElementNS(nameSpace, 'title');
      titleEl.textContent = displayText;
      titleEl.setAttribute('lang', 'en');
      groupEl.appendChild(titleEl);

      const rectEl = document.createElementNS(nameSpace, 'rect');
      rectEl.setAttribute('x', lastX);
      rectEl.setAttribute('width', itemCount);
      rectEl.setAttribute('height', height);
      rectEl.setAttribute('class', `chart__bar chart__bar--${CHART_COLORS[colorIdx]}`);
      groupEl.appendChild(rectEl);

      svgEl.appendChild(groupEl);
      colorIdx += 1;
      lastX += +rectEl.getAttribute('width');
    }
  }
})();

// ---

generateChart(document.querySelector('.js-chart'), {
   "Acetaminophen": 10,
   "Testosterone": 5,
   "Vitamin D": 3,
   "Spinach Capsule": 5,
   "Loratadine": 2,
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background-color: #c8bfcb;
}

.chart {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10rem;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.25rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

/* Actual color values could stay in CSS, if you want */
.chart__bar--white { fill: #d1cfd7; }
.chart__bar--red { fill: #e52a03; }
.chart__bar--orange { fill: #e79e04; }
.chart__bar--green { fill: #89c202; }
.chart__bar--blue { fill: #457bdc; }
```

```html
<h1>I'm Old, Here's Proof</h1>

<figure>
  <figcaption>Monday's Pills</figcaption>
  <svg class="chart js-chart"></svg>
</figure>
```

Now, this is just one example approach. I'm sure there are plenty of ways to accomplish each point. For another approach to a11y, I could also see the function generating some nice, [semantic HTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Accessibility/HTML#text_content) that then [gets visually hidden](https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/en/web/components-examples/accessible-hiding/) in favor of the generated SVG for sighted users. Pretty sure the SVG would no longer need any `<title>` tags or `aria-label` attributes that way. Regardless, I hope this adds a bit more to your toolbelt. Best of luck!